# "can't read superblock" when trying to mount usb drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I've recently got my Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm having issues mounting my external USB drive. Symptoms are the following:

- In `/dev` I only find `/dev/sda` and NOT `/dev/sda1`
- When trying to mount `/dev/sda /mnt/mydrive`, I get the message `mount: /dev/sda: can't read superblock`
- If I type `dmesg` I found a message that reads `[sda] READ CAPACITY failed`

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the hard drive is not getting enough power and that's why the Raspberry Pi can't read it properly. Some people suggest using a powered USB hub but in case you are powering your Pi with a decent power supply (e.g. 2A one), you can tell the Pi to increase the power supply to the USB ports by adding the option below

`max_usb_current=1`

to

`/boot/config.txt`

Just reboot your Pi and the USB port will provide enough power for your hard drive to work correctly. If the drive works correctly, you should find now a `/dev/sda1` that you can just mount.